# How to consolidate vue-tsc generated types in single file?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have Vue 3 project with a lot of typings there (every component has its own typed props etc). Before build I run this command: `vue-tsc --skipLibCheck --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly` and the problem is that creates `.d.ts` and `.d.ts.map` for every single `.vue/.ts` file in my project and it looks like this (consider dozens of components):

```
components
    componentA.vue
    componentA.vue.d.ts
    componentA.vue.d.ts.map
    componentB.vue
    componentB.vue.d.ts
    componentB.vue.d.ts.map

main.ts
main.d.ts
main.d.ts.map
```

It feels kinda wrong, but I couldn't find a way around.

Comment: What is the purpose? If you publish a library, there's probably supposed to be 1 bundled JS file, then it will have matching typings

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm not very experienced in building libraries, and I can't see how it's possible to get types from js file. I am pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but using vue-tsc was the only way to catch types on imporoted components

Comment: It's unclear what is your goal here. Why do you need to generate type files?